# Endless Pop-ups Trying to Save Word with linked Excel files on SharePoint

Tags: 2013, excel, popup, links, linked

I have a Word document saved on SharePoint 2013 that contains a large number of linked objects (tables from Excel files and bar charts from Excel files).

When I click Save on the Word doc, I start getting endless pop-ups from Excel saying "[Excel Doc Name] is already open. Reopening will cause any changes you made to be discarded. Do you want to reopen [Excel Doc Name]."

This occurs for every Excel file that's linked to in the Word doc.

I've tried: Unchecking the option for updating links when opening document, disabling add-ins unneeded add-ins, checking "Manual" update for every single link in "Edit Links."

Sometimes this doesn't happen at all. Other times it seems to happen when other users are also editing the document. Anyone have thoughts on a solution or how to prevent what seems like a background updating of links?